# Query data from MongoDb without a server

Tags: mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to decide between Firestore and MongoDB as the backend database, I have a doubt:

In Firebase:

- Firestore has security rules built so this makes it possible for clients to query data directly from Firestore without cloud functions and still be able to read & write data that he is authorized to do so.
- In MongoDb, the same logic of authorization to clients can be ensured with a server like Node.js or ktor application that acts as a mediator between the client and the database.

So my question is can clients query data directly from MongoDb and still ensure they read & write to data that they are authorized to without a server in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, clients cannot query data directly from mongoDB securely. Even firestore cannot do this.

Firestore does have server in between the client and database. It's just provided and managed by Firebase so from our eyes it looks like there is no server. If you want to do something similar with mongoDB, you would pretty much build what firebase has build on your own.

Comment: @AnudeepAnanth Glad I was able to help.